# Smoke simulation not working

Tags: fluid-simulation, smoke-simulation, cloth-simulation, effects, fire

I am new to Blender and I am using blender 3.0 I am trying to make a smoke simulation by quick effects but the smoke simulation is not working and also I have a chimney which should work as a effector. [image]
And also I want the smoke to flow faster. Example I want the smoke to touch the upper part of the cube in just 20 Frames any trick for it.

Here is the Blender file = https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZQ0Bu1cOaPad8leL_OrnCSskKUM4-XYx/view?usp=sharing

Comment: It actually works, I checked your scene and it seems that you didn't realize how massive your scene is, by my ruler in blender your power plant has 24 km across... due to that your smoke rises extremely slow and it looks like it doesn't move at all. Try to make it a more realistic size and set your settings again... Also please don't use values like 1000000000 in End value of Clip

Comment: The solution would be reducing my object size. Is that right.

Comment: pretty much, because if you watch closely even in your scene the smoke actually moves... but it rises so slowly that it looks like it doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

ok, here are several things you should do.

1. if you check here "face orientation" you will see red areas. These are bad. They will make problems if you are using in simulations/shading etc.

you can repair that in edit mode here:

[image]

2. you should not define everything as effector. Because whatever you add there, will be calculated by Blender in the simulation and will make it significantly slower.

...and to be honest...you used "realistic" values for the sizes. I don't know whether this is a good idea for smoke simulations...i would start with "normal sizes" like some meters...and if you have experience in that i would try bigger sizes.